# form, input problems when parsing webpage with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, input, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing webpages with selenium and beautifulsoup4,
and I have a problem with parsing specific webpage.

I got different html source pages when I actually view html source on that page, and parsing with selenium or bs4.
The difference is existence of form and input.

When I parse that page, I got html with

```
<form action="" method="post" name="fmove">
<input name="goAction" style="display:none" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I can't find what to input or submit.
Please let me understand this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Which website are you crawling?

Comment: it's disclosure site similar to 10-k

Comment: If there is any dynamic javascript involved, then in the source, you won't be able to see the form elements as they are appended dynamically, on the fly

Comment: as you are using selenium your rendering some JavaScript my guess is that you need to use execute_script() to get the form to finish rendering see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to concentrate on '[finding] what to input or submit' without touching on wider questions. Even so, what I tell you is not guaranteed to yield answers if code associated with that page does not arrange to fill the form's `action` attribute and/or some of its `input` elements with `name` and `value` pairs.

First, open the page in the Chrome browser. Use the item in the context menu to 'Inspect' the element on the screen to find the Javascript that finally submits that form. Put a breakpoint on the line in the code where this happens. Now reload the page (F5) and exercise the form. The code should stop at the breakpoint. You should be able to see the properties of the `form` element, including `action` and the name-value pairs, in the rightmost portion of the screen where you can copy them for use in your own code.

PS: I really must mention that it's difficult to be sure of a lot of this without knowing what site you're scraping. Good luck!